# Unable to find App in Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

The App shows correctly and is searchable via the old Marketplace interface:

https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=2333+15557384810033584025&category=&query=collavate

however, the same App is not searchable or findable in the New Marketplace.

Can you guys please help understand what's the problem here ?
Thanks.

Regards,
Pedro

Comment: Issue summary: 
I can't upload updated package in below page:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/edit/ihmojgcebknplmplakamkgnaaohcbpbe?hl=en
It's GAM.
[steps to reproduce]
1. go to https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/edit/ihmojgcebknplmplakamkgnaaohcbpbe?hl=en
2. click 'Upload update package' button
3. choose zip file and upload
[error message]
An error occurred: Failed to process your item.
This item is not an app, please remove app section from manifest.

Comment: Legacy packaged apps cannot be uploaded to the Chrome Web Store any more. More information can be found at http://blog.chromium.org/2014/06/migrate-your-legacy-packaged-apps-to.html
[manifest]
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Collavate",
"version": "0.0.2.0",
"description": "Assigning TAGs for your Google Drive files, design dynamic workflow process, and realtime file activity detection.",
"icons": {
"128": "icons/128x128-icon.png",
"16": "icons/16x16-icon.png"
},
"container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE"],
"api_console_project_id": "755727648277"
}

Comment: Did you do the migration of your app to the new marketplace? Are you experiencing this issue suddenly(published and working previously) or you are trying to publish the app recently? Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing) on how to publish on Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your manifest lacks the app.launch.web_url field, as shown in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing#manifest_file

Answer (score 0):

1. Basically, this is your issue. it was working totally fine with PUBLISHED and was showing on new google apps marketplace but it's not showing from a weeks or so. How can you explain this?
2. You said "your manifest lacks the app.launch.web_url field, as shown in the documentation:"

so I added them in manifest

But an error occured saying that
"this item is not an app, please remove app section from manifest."

So, this is not manifest issue.

3. Lastly, if you look at the chrome store, how come it shows under 'extension'? because marketplace connected chrome store app shouldn't appear on chrome store or even as an extension as it's for installation for google apps domain so it should be install-able within new/old marketplace only.